# Direct limit in Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

If we consider a directed direct system in the category of sets (order by inclusion), then the direct limit is just the union of all the sets appearing in the direct system.

Is this true more generally for a direct system in sets which is not directed? Or does the direct limit take a different form then?

Comment: Is a direct system not by definition directed?

Comment: Do you mean *colimits*?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft not by the definition I have (Rotman)

Comment: @Abramo could you put that definition here then?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg yes I mean colimits, also called direct limits. On the other hand limits are referred as inverse limits

Comment: @Abramo That is not the use of the terms I usually see. A colimit is a more general thing than a direct limit. Namely, a direct limit is a colimit where the arrows of the diagram turn the index set into a directed set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct limit of a diagram consisting of two sets $A$ and $B$ with no arrows between them is the disjoint union of the two sets, not their union. Even if $A=B$, the direct limit is then $A\coprod A$, the disjoint union of $A$ with itself (which can be realized as the set $\{(a,t)\mid a\in A,t\in \{\star, *\}\}$, where $\star \ne *$ are any two symbols).

Comment: Oh yes, now I see! I was missing the fact that even if A and B are in the system, $A\cap B$ may not be there. Thus we cannot check if two maps from A and from B agree... Nice point!